# Possible correction for Theorem 6.13 (Hopf-Rinow) Lee's book Riemannian Manifold 2nd Ed?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I think i found a notational error for this theorem from Lee's book Riemannian manifold p.108. 
[image]

I think the expression at the last sentence it should be $\tilde{\gamma}(t) = \gamma(t_j+t) $ instead of $\tilde{\gamma}(t) = \sigma(t_j+t)$. Or probably more clear $\sigma(t) = \tilde{\gamma}(t) = \gamma(t_j+t)$. Did anyone ever following this theorem and find this confusing ? I already seen the errata for this book (https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/Riemannian/errata.pdf)  but not found any correction for it. Is this true ? Or its just my ignorance.

Comment: It should be $\tilde \gamma (t_j +t) = \sigma(t)$?

Comment: We want $\sigma(0)=q_j= \gamma(t_j)$. I don't see how to get $q_j= \gamma(t_j)$ from $\tilde{\gamma}$ from above relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the formula is incorrect. But it should have been 
$$
\tilde\gamma(t) = \sigma(t-t_j) \text{ for $t\in (t_j-\delta,t_j+\delta)$}.
$$
(This is equivalent to the formula proposed by John Ma, but perhaps a little clearer.)  I had noticed this and fixed it in my draft second edition, but neglected to add the fix to my [correction list for the first edition](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/riemannian.html). It's now added. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

We want $\tilde \gamma : [0, t_j+ \delta) \to M$ so that $\tilde\gamma$ is an extension of $\gamma$ and $\tilde \gamma$ is a geodesic. We define $\tilde \gamma (t) = \gamma(t)$ on $[0,t_j)$. For $[t_j, t_j + \delta)$, define

$$\tilde \gamma (t_j+s)  = \sigma (s).$$

where $\sigma : [0, \delta)\to M$ is the geodesic with $\sigma (0) = \gamma(t_j)$ and $\sigma'(0) = \gamma'(t_j)$. Note that $\tilde \gamma(t) = \gamma(t)$ on $[t_j, b)$: Since they both satisfy

$$\gamma(t_j) = \tilde\gamma (t_j), \ \ \gamma'(t_j) = \tilde\gamma'(t_j) \ \ (= \sigma'(0)).$$